# How to download APK file with its extension from a web view?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I created an app with a web view. This web view opens a page with a lot of links to download APKs. The download process goes smoothly, BUT the downloaded apk file doesn't get its original name and extension.

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tech_news);

    techView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tech_webView);
    techView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    techView.loadUrl("http://egy-tech-droid.blogspot.com.eg/2015/08/blog-post.html");

    // This will handle downloading. It requires Gingerbread, though
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    // This is where downloaded files will be written, using the package
    // name isn't required
    // but it's a good way to communicate who owns the directory
    final File destinationDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getPackageName());
    if (!destinationDir.exists()) {
        destinationDir.mkdir(); // Don't forget to make the directory if
                                // it's not there
    }

    techView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            techView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition,
                        String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                    Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, contentDisposition);
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);



                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "downloading",
                            // To notify the user that the file
                            // is being downloaded.
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

I want the downloaded file to get its original name and extension, so when the user opens the file later from a file  explorer the system recognizes that file as an an apk, not just an unknown file.